# When a region or a country blocks a website, is domain IP address blocked or does domain resolution on their DNS server not happen?

Tags: dns, domain-name

I'm trying to access a certain website which has been blocked in my region. On trying to access it over mobile data, the website does not load.

If I directly type in the IP address that the domain points to, the website does not load.

However on using 1.1.1.1 app by cloudfare, the website loads.

So, my question is, is the IP address blocked or is the domain not resolved on the local region DNS server?

Comment: That entirely depends on the way the country implements the blocks.

Comment: Thats true but technically what I want to know is how does the website start working after I use the 1.1.1.1 DNS if the ip address is still blocked?

Comment: Your country doesn't block the IP address, but just removes the entries from DNS? Or they blocked an old IP address? Nobody knows, because nobody knows what country you are talking about. And that doesn't mean some other country won't do it differently.

Comment: Ah, that makes things a bit clearer. Are there other ways a website can be blocked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the question is "what are techniques to implement blocking on a state level", the best known example is the "Great Firewall" of China.

[This report](https://www.cs.tufts.edu/comp/116/archive/fall2016/ctang.pdf) (Chao Tang: In-depth analysis of the Great Firewall of China) describes the three most obvious techniques in detail, namely

- injecting TCP RST packets
- blocking specific IPs on all Chinese ISP's routers
- DNS tampering

The [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Firewall#Current_methods) additionally lists

- URL filtering using transparent proxies
- Quality of service filtering
- Man-in-the-middle attacks with TLS

The Great Firewall also implements other techniques, using deep packet inspection and heuristics to block protocols like Tor, SoftEther, and ssh. See [this CCC32 talk](https://media.ccc.de/v/32c3-7196-how_the_great_firewall_discovers_hidden_circumvention_servers).

As this is an ongoing arms race, I'd expect the Great Firewall to have implement even more techniques today.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didn't post my question well but this is the answer I was looking for.